# How would I delete a single column in all tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a column 'seq' in every table of my database that I would like to delete easily.

I have to do this on occasion in MySQL and am hoping this can be automated.

Comment: Write a script with `ALTER TABLE ...` syntax?

Comment: Can you please be more specific about this requirement and the reason for it? Do you want to actually `DROP` the column from each table? Or do you want to keep the column and erase the contents?

Comment: I wish to drop the column entirely. The issue is that seq is a sequence column that contains the Primary Key for each table. I am exporting data originally to MySQL and then using the data to port to Postgres, however, in Postgres the column already exists and is autoincrement, so I do not want the data in the seq column to carry over from MySQL to Postgres. Currently, I am deleting the column in each table one by one, but life would be so much easier automating the process.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a simple magical expression to just do this. You need to generate a list of SQL statements and then run them, somehow.

(Most database folks don't routinely drop columns from a database in production; it takes a lot of time during which the tables are inaccessible, and it's destructive. A fat-finger error could really mess you up.)

You might start by using the `information_schema` in MySQL to discover which of your tables have a `seq` column in them. This query will return that list of tables for the database you're currently using.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME 
   FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'seq'
```

You could then adapt that query to, for example, create a list of statements like this.

```
 SELECT DISTINCT 
        CONCAT('UPDATE ',TABLE_NAME, ' SET seq = 0;') AS stmt
   FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'seq'
```

This will produce a result set like this:

```
 UPDATE table_a SET seq = 0;
 UPDATE table_b SET seq = 0;
 UPDATE user SET seq = 0;
```

Then you could run these statements one by one. These statements will zero out your seq columns.

**Edit**

You can also do

```
CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',TABLE_NAME, ' DROP COLUMN seq;') AS stmt
```

to get a drop column statement for each table.

But, you might consider creating views of your tables that don't contain the `seq` columns, and then exporting to PostgreSQL using those views. If your tables are significant in size, this will save you a lot of time.

Comment: Wouldn't any value in seq (even 0) would give me an error on the Postgres import?